# Div element next to another div elemnt

Tags: html, css, microsoft-metro

I am trying to make a messaging app. I have found some good css from [metroui.org.ua](http://metroui.org.ua).
I want my app to look like this.

[image: This is the way I want the div to look like]

This is the code I have written.

```
 <div >
    <div style="display: inline; padding-left: 150px; width: 50px; float: left;">
        Hi Username,
        <br />
        Company
    </div>
    <div style="padding-left: 50px; padding-right: 200px; display: inline-block">
        <div class="balloon right">
            <div class="padding20">
                Balloon is represent to create information or dialog UI. You can put inside any
                of elements.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It works but when I put `<br/>` tag for company it messes up.
Also I am not getting the balloon right to display correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try putting Username and company into paragraph tags?
Like:

```
<p>Username</p>
<p>Company</p>
```

Try it and see if it works